# Tensorflow word2vector example error message

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed the latest version of Tensorflow in python3:

```
(tensorflow) [abigail@localhost anaconda3]$ python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
0.12.0-rc0
```

I wanted to run the word2vector example in the models/ directory. However, i received an error:

```
tensorflow) [abigail@localhost anaconda3]$ python models/embedding/word2vec.py --train_data=text8 --eval_data=questions-words.txt --save_path=/tmp
I tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec_kernels.cc:200] Data file: text8 contains 100000000 bytes, 17005207 words, 253854 unique words, 71290 unique frequent words.
Data file:  text8
Vocab size:  71290  + UNK
Words per epoch:  17005207
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models/embedding/word2vec.py", line 534, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "models/embedding/word2vec.py", line 517, in main
    model = Word2Vec(opts, session)
  File "models/embedding/word2vec.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "models/embedding/word2vec.py", line 368, in build_graph
    tf.contrib.deprecated.scalar_summary("NCE loss", loss)
  File "/home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(contrib, item)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib' has no attribute 'deprecated'
```

What is this error about?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Use the [version of `tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py) from the `r0.12` branch, to match the API of your installed version.

This error arises when you run a version of the tutorials that is not compatible with the version of TensorFlow that you have installed. The file `tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py` was [changed to use a new `tf.contrib.deprecated` API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/c532a5b558a451d599190f1dbbdf68f08dfcaa88#diff-bb5e615c74eba4ba74ef9fa709cc9dd6) after the 0.12 release was branched. TensorFlow is going through a period of flux as we clean up the APIs for a stable release, so during this period it will be important to use a version of the model code that matches the version you have installed.